# Intersection multiplicity in the non-algebraic case

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I know the definition of intersection multiplicity in algebraic geometry. However, I think it is possible to define it for some sort of non-algebraic functions such as $y=\sin x$.

> How to define this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we work in the category of holomorphic functions, then we can give the following definition, that generalises to the complex-analytic setting the classical intersection multiplicity used in algebraic geometry.

> **Definition.** Let $f$, $g$ be two holomorphic functions defined in a neighborhood of a point $\boldsymbol{z_0} \in \mathbb{C}^2$ and let $$X \colon \{f =0\}, \quad Y \colon  \{g=0\}$$ be the corresponding (germs of) analytic varieties. Then the intersection multiplicity of $X$ and $Y$ at the point $\boldsymbol{z_0}$ is $$m(X, \, Y; \, \boldsymbol{z_0})= \dim_{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^2, \,\boldsymbol{z_0} }/(f, \, g),$$
>   where $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^2, \,\boldsymbol{z_0} }$ stands for the analytic local ring of $\mathbb{C}^2$ at $\boldsymbol{z_0}.$

See for instance

T. De Jong, G. Pfister: *Local Analytic Geometry: Basic Theory and Applications*, Chapter 5.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this definition of local multiplicity generalizes directly to the case of an arbitrary smooth map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and any point $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$, it's just that the multiplicity need not be finite.  Just let $A_p$ be the ring of gerns of smooth functions defined in a neighborhood of $p$ and define the local multiplicity of $f$ at $p$ to be the dimension of the vector space $$A_p/(f^1,\ldots,f^m).$$  For properties of this multiplicity, see any treatment of the Malgrange Preparation Theorem.

Comment: Good point, thanks. In the real case, Malgrange's theorem plays the role of Weierstrass PreparationTheorem. By the way, it is surprising (at least for a non-expert like me) that we have such a result in the *smooth* case, not only in the real analytic one.